# How to pass a variable from ajax url parameter to laravel route?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I want to pass the sender id to laravel route like this, but seems my code is not working. Please specify the correct way to do it.

url: '/agent_close/{sender_id}',

```
function  closeChat(){
  sender = document.getElementById("sender_id").value;
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/agent_close/{sender_id}',
           data: "sender_id=" + sender, 
           success: function (data) {
                console.log('Message Closed');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred');
                console.log(data);
            },
         });
}
```

Route is:

```
Route::post('/agent_close/{sender_id}', 'AgentController@closeAgentThread');
```

Function:

```
   public function closeAgentThread($sender_id){
        $bot = new BotManController();
        return $bot->TakeThreadControl($sender_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url: '/agent_close/' + sender,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  sender = document.getElementById("sender_id").value;
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",  //you can use GET instead of POST
           url: '/agent_close/'+sender,   //this line used Route_URL instead Route_name
           data: "",   //can be null
           success: function (data) {
                console.log('Message Closed');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred');
                console.log(data);
            },
         });
}
```